# How to write the exactly same in LaTex in the easiest way?

Tags: framed

How to write the exact same in LaTex in the easiest way?

[image: o]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) What did you try so far? The `tcolorbox` package might be interesting.

Comment: Should it have to break across pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by @leandriis, here is an example of an environment that creates a box with the `tcolorbox` package.

The usage is

```
\begin{mybox}
....
\end{mybox}
```

The background color is `lightgray!50!white` by default, but you can change it if necessary.

The box is called here mybox, you can choose the name you want.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][lightgray!50!white]{sharp corners,colback=#1,colframe=black,
before upper={\rule[-3pt]{0pt}{10pt}},boxrule=2pt,
before skip=8pt, after skip= 8pt,
boxsep=5pt,%bottom=.5pt,%left=2pt,right=2pt,top=1pt
}

\begin{document}
Obviously, designed robots for structured environment with know and predictable conditions can be done by classic engineer-
\begin{mybox}As natural evolution has produced succefull life forms for practically all possible environment niches on Earth, it is plausible that artificial evolution can produce specialized robots for various environments and tasks
\end{mybox} 

Obviously, designed robots for structured environment with know and predictable conditions can be done by classic engineer-
\begin{mybox}[blue!20!white]As natural evolution has produced succefull life forms for practically all possible environment niches on Earth, it is plausible that artificial evolution can produce specialized robots for various environments and tasks
\end{mybox}
Obviously, designed robots for structured environment with know and predictable conditions can be done by classic engineer-
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! this is the exact answer.